# Writing a method that returns the last digit of an integer

Tags: java, integer, return, modulo

I'm given the following task, and can do it if I can use a string-

> Write a method named `lastDigit` that returns the last digit of an integer. For example, `lastDigit(3572)` should return `2`. It should work for negative numbers as well. For example, `lastDigit(-947)` should return `7`.

Where this problem gets tricky for me is that I am not allowed to use a `String` to solve this problem. Here's what I have thus far-

```
public static int lastDigit(int d) {  // d is the integer they call
    // i know that whatever goes here will be something like this
    int b = charAt(length - 1);
    return b;
}
```

Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: modulus : $a % $b  Remainder of $a divided by $b.  Decimal: `int % 10`

Comment: Modulus: digit = (num%10) (Watch for negatives!)

Comment: I don't really understand how this works. Can you give me more details?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
public static int lastDigit(int d) { 
     return Math.abs(d % 10);
}
```

Comment: This won't work for negative numbers.

Comment: @Renren29: Actually, it will work with negatives just fine. That's why there is a Math.abs.

Comment: Have you tried putting in -9 for d?

Comment: However, I'm confused why this works. Normally, -9 % 10 evaluates to 1, and then abs is applied to it...which should yield 1. However, I just ran this code and it produces 9. Which confuses me.

Comment: @Renren29 The `%` operator in Java will return negatives. `m % n` will have a result `x` such that `-m < x < m`. So `-9 % 10` will return `-9`; `Math.abs(-9)` is trivially 9.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int lastDigit(int d) { 
    return Math.abs(d-((int)(d/10))*10);
}
```

Comment: This works, thank you! But can you explain what d/10 * 10 does exactly?

Comment: @vhbravo This is not the best way. The comments guided you to the correct way to do it (modulus).

Comment: @vhbravo, for example (int)24/10 becomes 2, multiply 2 by 10 becomes 20.   The last digit is zeroed out, basically. But using modulo is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int lastDigit(int d) { 
    // using modulo
    if (d < 0) {
        return 10 - (d % 10);
    } else {
        return d % 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you add a second answer instead of editing your original one?